# Auto expand accordion on mouseover but prevent collapsing on mouseover

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am able to make my accordion automatically open a section on hover, but I don't know how to prevent it from collapsing a section when moving the mouse cursor over an active header of the accordion.

The following is my code:

```
    $("#accordion").accordion({
      event: 'mousedelay'
    }).delegate('.ui-accordion-header', 'mouseover', function() {
      clearTimeout($(this).closest('.ui-accordion').data('timeout'));
      $(this).closest('.ui-accordion').data('timeout', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $(this).trigger('mousedelay');
      }, this), 500));
    });
```

How do I change the code so an active section would only collapse on click (not mouseover)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling (this is first time I tried jquery-ui), I solved my own problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( { 
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      icons: null,
      animate: 500
    });
    $('#accordion').accordion({
      event: 'mousedelay'
    });
    $('.ui-accordion-header')
      .on('mouseover', function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).closest('.ui-accordion').data('timeout'));
        if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
          $(this).closest('.ui-accordion').data('timeout', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
            $(this).trigger('mousedelay');
          }, this), 500));
         };
        })
      .on('mouseleave', function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).closest('.ui-accordion').data('timeout'));
        })
      .on('click', function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).closest('.ui-accordion').data('timeout'));
        if (!$(this).next('div').is(':animated')) { $(this).trigger('mousedelay'); }
        });
  });
```

The code works like this:

- If the cursor is over an inactive header, the section expands after a delay
- If the cursor is over an active header, do nothing
- A mouse click toggles state of a section
- Mute mouse click if the accordion is being animated